# how to convert FileInfo object to string

Tags: c#, file, inputstream

i am picking txt files from a folder in that i am ordering those file according to their respective modify date after ordering these files i've to read contents of each one by one. what will be the possible solution for this. cause i am not able convert FileInfo object to string following is the snippet.
in output : i want all files sorted according to modified date and want to read it one by one.
thanks

```
string sourcePath = @"C:\sample\*.log";
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles(sourcePath).OrderBy(order => order.LastWriteTime).ToArray();
foreach (var item in files)
{
  listBox1.items.Add(item)
}
```

Comment: [File.ReadAllText Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Specify what exactly the problem is. What is your output? What did you expect to see? It appears you expect this to output the contents of the file magically. Please [RTFM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.tostring.aspx).

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `FileInfo.Name` or `FileInfo.FullName`?

Comment: in output : i want all files sorted according to modified date and want to read it one by one.

Comment: @user3584501 It makes it difficult to help you when you change the requirements completely from your original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `File.ReadAllText` and `FileInfo.FullName` property to get the path :

```
listBox1.items.Add(File.ReadAllText(item.FullName));
```

If you are only looking to get `FileName` of the file then use `FileInfo.Name` property like:

```
listBox1.items.Add(item.Name);
```

If you are looking to get file path then use `FileInfo.FullName` like:

```
listBox1.items.Add(item.FullName);
```

Comment: I thought the OP wanted to list the names of the files, not the contents of the files. Maybe they just need `item.Name`?

Comment: @drew_w, " i've to read contents of each one by one." is in the question, but still added it :)

Answer (score 1):

use the method File.ReadAllText to read each file.

```
        string sourcePath = @"C:\sample\*.log";
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles(sourcePath).OrderBy(order => order.LastWriteTime).ToArray();
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            string filecontent = File.ReadAllText(item.FullName);
            //do your job here 
             ......
            listBox1.items.Add(item.Name);
        }
```